# Meaning & Availability of HSI indicator

Tags: collegescorecard

Hello [collegescorecard] folk. I'm writing to see if I can get a closer - deeper look at the hsi indicator variable.

Two questions:

1) I'm seeing that it is available for 2005, only? I might be looking at that incorrectly. Am I right/wrong/other on the availability of that indicator over time?

2) In other data sources I understand that hsi indicators sometimes indicate that the institution is eligible for the formal HSI designation... not that it has received the HSI designation. So, the HSI indicator here in [collegescorecard], is it an indicator of eligibility? Or, is it an indicator of having received the designation?

Answer (score 0):

I have reached out to our data help desk ([scorecarddata@rti.org](http://mailto:scorecarddata@rti.org)) with your questions and I have received this response:

It is incorrect that the variable (HSI) is only available for 2005.  It is updated regularly but is only maintained in the most recent data file (2016-17).  This data element is provided by the Office of Postsecondary Education (OPE) and is current as of 2018.  OPE is responsible for identifying Hispanic-serving institutions (HSI). This indicator serves to show eligibility, and does not indicate any particular designation on the part of the U.S. Department of Education. See p. 7 of the [Data Documentation Report](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/assets/FullDataDocumentation.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Thanks so much. Very helpful. Especially the Data Documentation Report link.